# How to format date while parsing it from XLS file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, xlsx, xls

Im trying to parse a date value from csv & xls files. So the format should be mm/dd/yyy to further process in the backend. While reading xls format using xlsx module, I;m unable to get in the required format.
Please find my code below.

```
    var XLSX = require('xlsx');
         var workbook = XLSX.readFile(csvFilePath,{type:'binary',cellDates:true,dateNF:'mm"/"dd"/"yyyy'});
         var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;   
         console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]))
         jsonObj = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);

    But the output format of the date is 

         2020-11-20T00:00:00.000Z
```

But the required format should be 20/11/2020 (MM/DD/YYYY). Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: The example you provide `20/11/2020` can't be formatted as `MM/DD/YYYY` because 20 is not a valid month. The format you are dealing with is `DD/MM/YYYY` in which case the output you see is valid.

Comment: @JackHughes Even for "2020-02-03T00:00:00.000Z" date also I'm facing the same issue.